# How to Resize browserframe in cefpython

Tags: tkinter, cefpython

How can i resize the browserframe in cefpython?

I have a notebook tab with scroll but when i scroll leff/right and up/down the browserframe dont resize.

How can i do this, is there a way to resize the browserframe in order to implement in the scroll script?

this is my scroll script, i need to resize the browserframe with the scroll.

for example, i scroll right and the browserframe witdh increases

```
import ctypes
import platform
from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import sys
from cefpython.examples.tkinter_ import logger

WINDOWS = platform.system() == 'Windows'
LINUX = platform.system() == 'Linux'
MAC = platform.system() == 'Darwin'


class BrowserFrame(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, text='Browser', **kw)
        self.browser = None
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.on_configure)

    def winfo_id(self):
        return super.winfo_id()

    def get_window_handle(self):
        if MAC:
            from AppKit import NSApp
            import objc
            return objc.pyobjc_id(NSApp.windows()[-1].contentView())
        elif self.winfo_id() > 0:
            return self.winfo_id()
        else:
            raise Exception('Could not obtain window handle!')

    def cef_loop(self):
        cef.MessageLoopWork()
        self.after(10, self.cef_loop)

    def on_configure(self, event):
        global urlset
        urlset = "http://www.google.com"
        if self.browser is None:
            # create the browser and embed it in current frame
            self.update()
            rect = [150,0, self.winfo_width()+100, self.winfo_height()]
            cef_winfo = cef.WindowInfo()
            win_id = self.get_window_handle()
            cef_winfo.SetAsChild(win_id, rect)
            self.browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(cef_winfo, url=urlset)

            print("self: ", self)
            print("rect: ", rect)
            print("win_id: ", win_id)
            print("self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height(): ", self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height())

            # start the browser handling loop
            self.cef_loop()

        # resize the browser
        if WINDOWS:
            ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowPos(
                self.browser.GetWindowHandle(), 0,
                0, 0, event.width, event.height, 0x0002)
        elif LINUX:
            self.browser.SetBounds(0, 0, event.width, event.height)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    WindowUtils = cef.WindowUtils()
    sys.excepthook = cef.ExceptHook  # To shutdown all CEF processes on error
    settings = {}
    if MAC:
        settings["external_message_pump"] = True

    cef.Initialize(settings=settings)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w - 250, h - 300))
    root.title('Test')

    container = Frame(root)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
    scrollbar_x = Scrollbar(container, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
    scrollbar_y = Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    scrollable_frame = Frame(canvas)
    scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
    canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar_x.set)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_y.set)

    def on_mousewheel(event):
        shift = (event.state & 0x1) != 0
        scroll = -1 if event.delta > 0 else 1
        if shift:
            canvas.xview_scroll(scroll, "units")
        else:
            canvas.yview_scroll(scroll, "units")
    canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", on_mousewheel)


    leftfrm = tk.LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="Left", padx=5, pady=5, bg='red')
    leftfrm.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news', pady=2)

    home_browser = tk.LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="home_of_the_browser", padx=5, pady=5, bg='blue')
    home_browser.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=2, ipady=200, ipadx=900)
    home_browser.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    home_browser.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    browser_frame = BrowserFrame(home_browser)
    browser_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=('news'))
    browser_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    browser_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    browser_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)
    root.update()

    print("home_browser.winfo_rootx(),home_browser.winfo_rooty()",home_browser.winfo_rootx(),home_browser.winfo_rooty())
    print("->", leftfrm)  # labelframe
    print("->", home_browser)  # labelframe2
    print("->", browser_frame)  # !labelframe2.!browserframe

    for x in range(1, 25):
        tk.Label(leftfrm, text=f"Link {x}", bg='yellow').grid(row=x, column=0)





    container.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
    scrollbar_x.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
    scrollbar_y.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    canvas.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

    root.mainloop()
    cef.Shutdown()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: do you want to resize the widget or scroll it? and [edit] your question to include a [mre]

Comment: Why do you expect the frame will be resized when scrolling?

Comment: i dont expect it, but i need it to resize or move because when i move the scroll the browser frame dont move.  since i need the browser frame to be bigger than the space i have left, this is just for laptops, for widescreen its ok

Comment: But there is nothing in the code related to what you said ___browser frame___.  You need to provide [mre].

Comment: updated my question with a reproducible example